# How to export data from Hive to Cassandra?

Tags: hive, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, cassandra-cli

Is there a way to export data from Hortonworks Hive to Apache Cassandra without using ETL tools?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database "export" and a table "myview" inside of it.

```
create database export;
use export;
create table myview as select <put your query here>
```

Then use "desc" to get the full directory path:

```
describe myview.
```

From the directory path, you can point cassandra to that hdfs location and import it from hdfs.

Disclaimer:  this process is only for smaller tables since your "myview" is not partitioned. It is not suitable for large ones that should have partitions defined on them.

Comment: Not clear on above steps; can you please elaborate? How Hadoop and Cassandra are connected in above example? Export is not table, I want to know how to transfer data from Hadoop cluster/hive table to Cassandra table.

Comment: hi javadba, I created database in hive, and the 'use export' an then created a table with required data. Now how to point Cassandra to Hive? Both are two different clusters and different machines. Even if those are on same machines, I don't know how to connect. I couldn't find google on cassandra to point to hdfs location; can you please provide me sample code? I am trying Github 'cassandra-hive' storage handlers; but I would like to use your steps if these are simple. Thank you.